# Бонус за подключение к своей учетной записи других аккаунтов

Tags: поддержка, справка

В [Справка > Репутация и модерация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) есть пункт: `бонус за подключение к своей учетной записи других аккаунтов: +100 для каждого сайта (выдается только один раз для каждого сайта).` О каких аккаунтах/сайтах идёт речь (об учётных записях логина, сайтах Stack Exchange, др.)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если у вас достаточно (200 и более) репутации на одном из сайтов сети Stack Exchange, то при регистрации на других сайтах вы автоматически получаете дополнительные 100 очков репутации, которые снимают с вас новичковые ограничения.

При этом неважно, что произошло раньше - регистрация на сайте или получение необходимой репутации.

При объединении нескольких учетных записей в одну происходит то же самое.

Буквально следующий абзац из той же статьи:

> Если вы опытный пользователь сети Stack Exchange **с репутацией 200 или более** хотя бы на одном из сайтов, вы получите стартовый бонус +100 к репутации на других сайтах, что позволит вам обойти ограничения для новых пользователей.

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под достаточно?

Comment: @val 200 и более